# Incrementing the value in a html5 text box not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on an application where I have several text boxes with floating values and I am trying to add an increment and decrement ticker to the existing value in the text box using the following tag.

```
<input type="number" step="0.5" id="txbBid" data-bind="value: Bid" />
<input type="number" step="0.5" id="txbOffer" data-bind="value: Offer" />
```

That works fine only with chrome and doesn't work with any other web browser. Is there any other way I can do that(probably with java script) and also I didnt like the number feature as it sometimes keep on fluctuating even when I don't click on the ticker.

Comment: I think, This is not supported in all recent browser so javascript would be the best idea to achieve this goal

Comment: Any Ideas on how to do it in java script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just get the element by its ID and add or sustract the value you want!

here you ahve the HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="txbBid" data-bind="value: Bid" />
<input type="text" value="0" id="txbOffer" data-bind="value: Offer" />
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add">
<input type="button" onclick="sustract()" value="Sustract">
```

And here the JS.

```
var step = 1;

function add(){
  document.getElementById('txbBid').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('txbBid').value) + step;
}

function sustract(){
document.getElementById('txbBid').value = 
parseInt(document.getElementById('txbBid').value) - step;
}
```

And the code running on JSbin: http://jsbin.com/UGoLOSec/2/edit